# Android crash data sent to Firebase Crashlytics and Google Play Store

Tags: android, firebase, crash, crashlytics, tracking

I develop an android app, where we use firebase crashlytics. I am curious to know which data gets collected by Firebase Crashlytics and the Google Play Store for each app crash by default. I could not find enough information about my question in the docs of the two applications. What I found out so far:

**Firebase Crashlytics**

Data visible in the firebase console:

- stacktrace of the crash
- smartphone brand (e.g. Huawei)
- smartphone model (e.g. P30 Pro)
- orientation (portrait/landscape)
- free RAM space
- free disk space
- android version
- if device is rooted
- date and time of the crash
- app version and build number

I found a full list of data that can be exported from firebase to BigQuery, but I am unsure which of the fields are really sent from my application.
See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export

Firebase crashlytics stores the stacktrace for 180 days. The instance id is stored until a deletion is requested.
See: https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy

The data is sent to firebase crashlytics with the first start of the app after a crash, so it is not 100% accurate.

**Google Play Store**

Data visible in the Play Store Console:

- stacktrace of the crash
- smartphone brand (e.g. Huawei)
- smartphone model (e.g. P30 Pro)
- free RAM space
- android version
- date and time of crash
- app version and build number

I could not find a complete list of all data, that gets send to Google Play Store.

Crash data is just sent if the user has opted in to automatically share usage and diagnostics data on his phone.
See: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=0 (Under the section: Crashes & application not responding errors (ANRs))

I guess the data sending to Google Play Store is not dependent on a restart of the app. This would mean the number of crashes are more accurately tracked by the Play Store. Am I right?

How long saves Google Play Store the crash report data?

Comment: In reviewing the Crashes and ANRs of the Google Play Console, it defaults to showing the last 28 days and you can expand this to 60 days.